# Cronjob setting on shared hosting

Tags: laravel, cron

I'm trying to run this as document says:

```
cd /home/dastanez/zanganli.ir && php artisan schedule:run >> /home/dastanez/report.txt 2>&1
```

It fails and according to report.txt :

```
proc_close() has been disabled for security reasons
```

most of the time contacting to administrators doesn't help.
Whatever I say they would say you should buy VPS.

The first solution came to my mind was to create a crob/job.php file and autoload everything there and write my codes there but this way I'm gonna lose \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule features.

Comment: What does it display when you write the command `crontab -e` in the terminal?

Comment: I don't have access to ssh

Comment: Do you have cpanel access?

Comment: yes. but not terminal.

Comment: At first my terminal access was disabled by default. After talking with the administrator they enabled it. Also I somewhere found to enable the terminal shell access. Although this might not be the solution but you could give it a try

Comment: I will give it a try. I was wrong about choosing laravel. I should've choosen something like CodeIgniter. Laravel has a lot of problems on shared hostings. Thank you.

Comment: Laravel is not the problem my friend. Maybe the shared hosting you got has limited features. I have been using Laravel for my project in the shared hosting from Namecheap for many years. Yes shared hosting has little features. But it is worth the money.

Comment: `*/5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/project/example_folder_name/artisan send-mail:authentication > /dev/null 2>&1` is the command I used. Maybe the example command might help you.